# Vopenka's principle is equivalent to the existence of a strong compactness cardinal for any "logic"?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

According to [Cantor's attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Vopenka#Strong_Compactness_of_Logics), Vopenka's principle is equivalent to the existence of a strong compactness cardinal for any "logic". But I can't find a definition of what a "logic" is either there or in any of the cited references.

**Question:** What is a "logic" in the sense of this statement?

Some examples are given: apparently infinitary logic $L_{\kappa\kappa}$ is a "logic", and infinitary higher(but finite)-order logic $L_{\kappa\kappa}^n$ is a "logic". Thus Vopenka's principle should imply the existence of a proper class of strongly compact cardinals, and even a proper class of extendible cardinals.

But I don't think it's supposed to be as simple as "Vopenka's principle is equivalent to a proper class of extendibles", so there must be more "logics" than these. The next thing I can think of is some sort of infinitary-order infinitary logic $L^\alpha_{\kappa\kappa}$. It would also make sense to consider structures with infinitary operations. I don't know if there's a large cardinal principle associated to strong compactness for either of these sorts of logic.

And then of course there are "logics" such as various flavors of type theory (which higher order logic starts to resemble anyway!) but just for cultural reasons, I doubt that "logic" is meant to encompass anything along these lines.

Comment: Pardon my naiveté but when Vopenka's principle is stated in terms of the 'category of ordinals', do we mean the ordinals as objects with (some type of) order-preserving functions as arrows or the ordinals as a poset category?

Comment: @AlecRhea I'm not sure precisely which formulation of Vopenka's principle you're referring to, but I suspect it's one which says "there is no full embedding $Ord \to Gph$" (or various other categories or classes of categories may be substituted for the categorh $Gph$ of graphs). In this context, $Ord$ is viewed as a large poset. Equivalently, it is the category of well-ordered sets $\alpha$ and maps which preserve the operation $min: P(\alpha) \setminus \{\emptyset\} \to \alpha$ (since any such map $\alpha \to \beta$ just embeds $\alpha$ as an initial segment of $\beta$).

Comment: I would guess that the statement is referring to the notion of "logic" as defined in "abstract model theory". You can find the definition in the section on Lindstrom's theorem in Chang & Keisler's *Model Theory* or in the book *Model Theoretic Logics* edited by Barwise and Feferman.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't see how to view second-order or higher-order logic as an example of an abstract logic in Chang and Keisler's sense.

Comment: @TimCampion Hmm... that's what I get for posting a reference without actually remembering what's in that reference! I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Too late! Ninja'd. You had the right textbook, though, "Model Theoretic Logics"

Comment: Ok, I found my copy of Chang & Keisler and looked at their definition of abstract logic (Definition 2.5.1 on p. 128). I don't see any issue with making second-order or higher-order logics into abstract logics, as long as their given their intended semantics where e.g. the semantics of quantifying over a predicate is quantifying over the full power set of a structure. What part of the definition seems like a problem to you?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Well first of all, they work with a one-sorted vocabulary. But to do second order logic, I would expect you need at least one additional sort for second-order variables. And the renaming property seems to preclude doing any kind of tricky "type-inference" based on set-theoretic properties of the elements of the vocabulary.

Comment: Right, they're definitely only working with single-sorted first-order vocabularies. But the point is that to specify a vocabulary for higher-order logics, you just need to specify a vocabulary for first-order logic. The other "sorts" that higher-order variables can live in are derived from the sorts of elements. The definition is essentially saying that an abstract logic as to have some constructs of first-order logic, but it doesn't preclude the logic having additional constructs. And it requires that the semantics be defined on ordinary first-order structures in a reasonable way. (continued)

Comment: ... And indeed, the semantics for higher-order logics (here again I'm talking about "standard semantics", not "Henkin semantics") are defined on first-order structures.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh. I guess I find that disappointing. For example, this means that I can't axiomatize a topological space in second-order logic using a second-order predicate "is an open set". In general, it means that I can't "relativize" things -- if $A$ is a second-order entity in a model of a theory $T$, there's no second-order theory $T[A]$ whose formulas are formulas of $T$ with parameter $A$.

Comment: That's right, you can't do that in the classical second-order/higher-order logic. Of course, you could formulate a logic where the vocabulary has higher order symbols in it. But classical higher-order logics don't have such symbols built into the vocabulary - they only allows you to quantify over higher-order variables. Note, though, that you can axiomatize topological spaces via a third-order formula $\varphi(X)$ in the empty vocabulary with a single third-order free variable $X$, so that $M\models \varphi(\tau)$ if and only if $\tau$ is a topology on $M$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## ORIGINAL RESPONSE:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273786?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents Is the article where it is from. It seems to have never been added to the library, which would be my fault.

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235417266 is the first chapter of the textbook where I personally found it, although I would use the JSTOR article in the library of Cantor's Attic after this post.

The massive textbook I used is called "Model-Theoretic
Logics" by the "Ω-Group" (the coolest pen-name for a group of mathematicians). In Part F, this equivalence is proven.

Chapter XVII is "Set-theoretic definability of logics" (written by Väänänen, one of my heroes) which is where this comes from. The definition is quite nuanced, but it is a great read. I recommend this textbook.

### What Is a Logic? (loose definition)

We start with a "vocabulary." $\tau$ is often used for this type of object; it is defined as a (nonempty) class of constant symbols, finitary predicate symbols, and finitary function symbols (simple enough). However, you also have to have "sort symbols" for every function symbol and every constant symbol, and furthermore you have to have sort symbols for every argument of every relation symbol and every input of every function symbol.

The sort symbols are just for well-defining "terms" and their syntactics. The "$\tau$-terms" are built up of just function symbols applied to constant symbols, each of which are then given a "sort" to help define things later.

Using the sort, you can well-define the number of inputs in a given "formula" made out of $\tau$.

An "abstract logic" $\mathcal{L}$ gives every vocabulary $\tau$ a class $\mathcal{L}(\tau)$ of formulae and "atomic $\tau$-formulae of $\mathcal{L}$." More important is that it gives every $\tau$ a relation $\models^\tau$ which defines semantics: how a structure interprets a formula of $\mathcal{L}$.

The kind of logic we are talking about has been formalized by Väänänen, but it suggests that the definitions of $\models^\tau$ and deciding what things are atomic formulae are recursive somewhat (synctatic) and furthermore there is a set $A$ such that every formula of $\mathcal{L}$ is in $A$ and that $\mathcal{L}$ can easily describe this set $A$ (the syntax of $\mathcal{L}$ is representable).

There is a lot more to this definition that I haven't talked about, so this is a very rough summary. I urge you to take a look at the book instead of just taking my word (I am in no ways an expert).

---

## Addendum:

I've recently circled back to this problem after nearly 5 years, and I now realize that the actual argument for this proof isn't as complicated as I thought it was.

For anybody reading this, here is a simple definition of a logic, so that VP is equivalent to the statement that every logic has a strong compactness cardinal.

A **logic** consists of two parts:

- The *language*, which is a proper class $\mathcal{L}$ of $\tau$-*sentences* for each relational signature $\tau$; these are functions $\varphi:x\rightarrow\tau$ for some set $x$. The class of $\tau$-sentences for a particular $\tau$ may be denoted $\mathcal{L}[\tau]$.
- The *semantics*, which is a proper class $\models_{\mathcal{L}}$ of tuples $(\mathcal{M},\varphi)$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\tau$-structure for some signature $\tau$ and $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}$ is a $\tau$-sentence.

We require that it satisfies the following conditions:

- Isomorphism invariance: if $\mathcal{M}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$, then for any $\varphi$ in $\mathcal{L}$, $$(\mathcal{M}\models_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi)\leftrightarrow(\mathcal{N}\models_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi)$$
- Reduction invariance: if $i:\tau\rightarrow\sigma$ is a monomorphism of relational structures, and $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-structure, then for any $\varphi:x\rightarrow\tau$ in $\mathcal{L}$, the composition $i\circ\varphi:x\rightarrow\sigma$ is also in $\mathcal{L}$, and $$(\mathcal{M}|_{\tau}\models_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi)\leftrightarrow(\mathcal{M}\models_{\mathcal{L}} i\circ\varphi)$$

These properties essentially guarantee that each $\varphi$ is a statement, with parameters in $V$, about the relations in the structure; and nothing more.

Of course, in the above formulation, logics like $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$ can be construed, which have no strong compactness cardinal no matter how you slice it. We can say that the logic is **small** when there is some fixed set $X$ such that each $\tau$-sentence $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}$ is a function $x\rightarrow\tau$ for some $x\in X$.

As an example, $\tau$-sentences of $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}$ may be construed as functions $x\rightarrow\tau$ for $x\in H_\kappa$. So, this logic is small.

---

#### The proof:

VP is equivalent to the statement that for every class $A$ there is a stationary class of $A$-extendible cardinals. So, assuming VP, there is a $\models_{\mathcal{L}}$-extendible cardinal $\kappa$ such that the set $X$ mentioned above is in $V_\kappa$.

Let $\Sigma\subset\mathcal{L}[\tau]$ be such that for every $t\subset\Sigma$ with $|t|<\kappa$, there is a $\tau$-structure $\mathcal{M}_t$ such that $\mathcal{M}_t\models_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi$ for all $\varphi\in t$. In other words, let $\Sigma$ be a $\kappa$-satisfiable $\mathcal{L}$-theory. Then, let $j:(V_\eta;\in,\models_{\mathcal{L}})\rightarrow (V_\theta;\in\models_{\mathcal{L}})$ be an elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$, such that $\Sigma\in V_\eta$ and each $\mathcal{M}_t\in V_\eta$.

Since $V_\eta$ witnesses that every subset of $\Sigma$ of size below $\kappa$ has a model, by elementarity and $\models_{\mathcal{L}}$-correctness, $V_\theta$ witnesses that every subset of $j(\Sigma)$ of size below $j(\kappa)$ has a model. In particular, $j"\Sigma$ is a subset of $j(\Sigma)$ of size $\kappa$, so it must have a model $\mathcal{M}$. However, we are not quite done.

This $\mathcal{M}$ is a $j(\tau)$-structure, satisfying every member of $j"\Sigma$. So, we don't quite have a model of $\Sigma$ per se. However, every $\varphi\in j"\Sigma$ is of the form $j(\varphi)$ for $\varphi:x\rightarrow\tau$. *Because $x\in V_\kappa$*, we have that $j(\varphi)=j|_\tau\circ\varphi:x\rightarrow j(\tau)$, and $j|_\tau:\tau\rightarrow j(\tau)$ is a monomorphism of signatures.

So, by reduction invariance, $\mathcal{M}|_\tau$ is a model of every $\varphi\in\Sigma$, completing the proof.

The reverse direction is not as hard. Given a proper class $A$ of $\tau$-structures, we wish to find a first-order elementary embedding between two of its members. Because first-order logic is isomorphism invariant, WLOG $A$ is closed under isomorphism. For each monomorphism $i:\tau\rightarrow\sigma$, we can consider the class $A^i$ of $\sigma$-structures who reduce to a member of $A$. If there is an elementary embedding in $A^i$ for some $i$, then since first-order logic is reduction invariant, there is an elementary embedding in $A$.

So, we construct the logic by starting with first-order logic, adding a $\tau$-sentence satisfied only by members of $A$, and then for each monomorphism $i:\tau\rightarrow\sigma$ adding a $\sigma$-sentence satisfied only by members of $A^i$. This logic is readily seen to be isomorphism invariant and reduction invariant by the exposition above. It is also small. If it has a strong compactness cardinal, pick any structure $\mathcal{M}$ in $A$ of size greater than that of the cardinal, and consider its elementary diagram in this logic. Add to it a new constant symbol and, for each $x\in\mathcal{M}$, an axiom stating that $x$ is not equal to the new constant symbol. This theory is clearly $\kappa$-satisfiable, so by strong compactness it is satisfiable. But any model of it must be a member of $A$ admitting a nontrivial elementary embedding from $\mathcal{M}$. QED

Comment: More precisely, the result in question is Part F, Chapter XVIII, Theorem 1.5.17 on p. 661 of *Model Theoretic Logics* and is attributed to Makowsky.

Comment: @KeithMillar There are a bunch of _classes_ which appear both in Vopenka's principle and in the definition of a logic. In this theorem, are these to be interpreted as definable classes in ZFC, or are we working in NBG or something?

Comment: I suspect this notion of "logic" is not the "utlimate" notion of "logic" for which a similar theorem holds. For example, Theorem 6.9 [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(78)90031-1) suggests to me that one could get a similar theorem for higher-order logics which allow the vocabulary to include higher-order function / relation symbols.

Comment: The definition of "logic" in _Model-Theoretic Logics_ is in Ebbinghaus' Ch II. It can be summarized as follows. Many-sorted first-order vocabularies form a category $Voc$ under injective well-typed maps. First-order structures form a functor $Str: Voc^{op} \to Cl$ where $Cl$ is the category of classes. A "logic" is a functor $Lang: Voc\to Cl$ equipped with a [dinatural transformation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation) $\models:Lang \times Str \to 2$ where $2$ is the constant functor at $\{0,1\}$. Of course, there's still the ambiguity of what a class or class function is.

Comment: @TimCampion This logic already includes higher-order function and relation symbols, as it is many-sorted. But that definition is much more formal and accurate, even though it is a lot more complex.

Comment: @KeithMillar I don't understand your second sentence -- I just gave Ebbinghaus' complete definition in one comment and it didn't seem particularly complex to me. Regarding your first sentence, the fact that a logic may have many sorts does not imply that its sorts may adequately represent higher-order entities. In fact, I see two ways to try to fit higher-order symbols in Ebbinghaus' framework, both of which seem problematic. Let's say we want to formalize a theory with one first-order sort $X$ and one second-order sort $P$ where $P$ represents the powerset of $X$.

Comment: Then for each $x \in X$ and $R \in P$ we need some sort of formula $\epsilon(x,R)$ whose interpretation is that $x \in R$. The first option would be to add $\epsilon$ to the signature. But then by isomorphism-invariance, we are essentially required to use Henkin semantics, which means we're not really doing second-order logic at all. The second option would be to have a rule in our logic which adds a formula $\epsilon(x,R)$ automatically, and stipulates that in the semantics, this formula can only be satisfied if the interpretation $[P]$ of $P$ is the powerset of $[X]$.

Comment: But we can't actually do this, again because of isomorphism-invariance.

Comment: @TimpCampion by complex I mean that it isn't quite intuitive or layman. However, you are correct that it is much more compact and quicker/more straightforwards. You are also correct that it can't represent all higher-order entities.

Comment: @KeithMillar I see, thanks. Sorry to harp on about this, but what I'm driving at is that the sorts in Ebbinghaus' notion of "logic" have _nothing whatsoever_ to do with higher order entities -- in fact, the isomorphism-invariance rule for satisfaction entails that the sorts of the vocabulary may _only_ be first-order sorts, and therefore the functions / relations in the vocabulary are also necessarily first-order, just as in Chang and Keisler's definition, or in classical higher-order logic according to Alex Kruckman in the comments above.

Comment: @TimCampion No problem, it's good to formally define things in a compact and straightforwards way.

Comment: Look at http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtadb/AccessibleCategories2018/Magidor.pdf